# Python os.walk on a different computer on the same network

Tags: python, operating-system

I would like to do an os.walk in python 2.7 in windows 7 but on a computer that is on the same network. Something like os.walk('\192.168.0.2') but this doesn't work. Is this possible?

Comment: The other computer would have to share their file system in some way. There is an option to share a directory in windows 7, but I hav not worked with windos in months.

Comment: I have file sharing enabled but os.walk doesn't work with it

Comment: @user1580428: I think you need more backslashes there. Also remember that backslashes need to be escaped to `\\`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `net use` or a UNC path.

Or try Linux, you'd probably be better off with it than Windows.

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/p/net-use-command.htm

http://www.uwplatt.edu/oit/terms/uncpath.html

In python, using Windows paths is often easier if you use, for example,
 `r'\\hostname\share'` rather than `'\\\\hostname\\share'`.

Comment: Yeah, you'll do it by walking the local filesystem at a filepath which some other tool/software provides to make the remote files system appear to be local.

Answer (score 0):

My thought is also to go for Linux, or at least, Windows with SSH service.

1. [Set up public key authentication over SSH](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/532.cfm), and make sure you can ssh to that Windows machine (with SSH service on, of course) without password and password phrase.
2. Make use of [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.3/index.html), a Python (2.5 or higher) library and command-line tool for streamlining the use of SSH for application deployment or systems administration tasks.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, what I did was opened File Explorer, and navigated to the (sub)folder of interest on the network drive, and right clicked on Properties.  Copy the Location information, and paste that into your Python file.

Ex.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("//<network name>/<folder>/<sub-folder1>/<sub-folder2>/.../<sub-folderN>"):
    for file in files:
        print(file)
```